# ImageButton with image icon, colored background and border

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton

I would like to create an ImageButton drawable resource file that has both an image (not to be expanded for the background), a colored background and a right and bottom border. Also, I want to have the state_pressed, state_selected and the default state with different settings.

Right now I've managed to create the xml resource file for the image for all the states:

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/emailselected" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/emailselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/emailselected" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/emailseleted" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/email" />
```

I also have the background and right and bottom border xml resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I would like to combine all these in one single resource file. Is it possible?
So basically I would like:

- Button pressed: the background turns blue and the icon is "email_selected"
- Button selected: the background turns blue and the icon is "email_selected"
- Default: the background turns gray and the icon is "email"

I've tried to combine the two resource files in one by having the "android:state" in the items for the background colors "orange" and "gray" but it simply doesn't work.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to use the separate background resource file and use the selector with the state pressed and selected items. I guess you cannot have the "background" and "drawable" in the same resource file. Here's my code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```